# In Minecraft I’ve been trying to make a water particle effect, but it never works

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have cheats on, am in creative mode, got my x y and z coordinates right, but it keeps on telling me the delta is wrong. I’ve tried multiple commands. `/particle dripwater 856 69 -53 1 1 1 8000`, I’ve tried it with `~`’s, I’ve tried to use `/execute`, I’ve tried put `x=, y=,` etc. can someone please help?

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: `dripwater` is not a particle name. Where did you get that from?

Answer (score 2):

you can put this into a repeating command block to create something that looks a bit like rain that everyone can see.

```
/particle minecraft:dripping_water ~ ~10 ~ 2 1 2 1 10 normal @a
```

the syntax for `/particle` is:

```
/particle <name> [<pos>] [<delta>] [<speed>] [<count>] [<normal|forced>] [<viewers>]
```

where `<name>` is the name of the particle effect that you want to use

`<pos>` is where you want to use the effect

`<delta>` is how big the area where the particles can spawn should be, using `<pos>` as the center point

`<speed>` determins how fast the particle is animated (it does not seem to make a difference for me in the command above)

`<count>` determins how many particles should be spawned

`<forced|normal>` decides if the particles are forced, or if they are normal, which means that they obey the graphic settings of a player (for example by spawning fewer, or none)

`<viewers>` decides who can see the particles.

[more on `/particle`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/particle)

Comment: I personally quite like `/execute at @p run particle minecraft:dripping_water ~ ~3 ~ 10 5 10 1 3 normal @p` combined with a low rendering distance (mine was 2) for a mysterious, or special looking effect, which I found while testing